# Centering MDlist Text under ScrollView KivyMD

Tags: python, list, kivy, scrollview

I am struggling to center the text in ScrollView.

My KV code is the following :

```
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem

kv =""""
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False  # Important for MD compliance
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Single-line item"
"""

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sv = ScrollView()
        ml = MDList()
        sv.add_widget(ml)
        contacts = ["Paula", "John", "Kate", "Vlad"]
        for c in contacts:
            ml.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(
                    text=c
                )
            )
        return sv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

This is what the screen looks like :
[image: Centering Issue]

Please help!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]..

Comment: @noEmbryo Done. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, is to subclass the `OneLineListItem`, so you can add a `halign` argument for horizontal alignment:

```py
class OneLineListItemAligned(OneLineListItem):
    def __init__(self, halign, **kwargs):
        super(OneLineListItemAligned, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids._lbl_primary.halign = halign


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sv = ScrollView()
        ml = MDList()
        sv.add_widget(ml)
        contacts = ["Paula", "John", "Kate", "Vlad"]
        for c in contacts:
            ml.add_widget(OneLineListItemAligned(halign="center", text=c))
        return sv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

P.S. The `kv` part of the code is not used in your example...

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/uix/list.py

OneListItem inherits from BaseListItem which has a protected property _txt_left_pad.  This is a protected variable and shouldn't be messed because the material design standard does not allow for centered text in list items.  But its python so nothing is stopping you from messing with it and increasing the padding on the left till its centered or moved in enough to your liking.  There may be other ways to do this also by messing the OneListItem's children and changing the prosperities of the children.

Comment: Please anyway you can help me out

Answer (score 0):

By adding the list item like this you get an amount of spaces enough for the text to be exactly in the center

```py
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem

kv =""""
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False  # Important for MD compliance
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Single-line item"
"""

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sv = ScrollView()
        ml = MDList()
        sv.add_widget(ml)
        contacts = ["Paula", "John", "Kate", "Vlad"]
        for c in contacts:
            text = "my text"
            ml.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f"{' ' * (ml.width - (len(text) * 2))}{text}"))
        return sv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```